# Office UI Fabric JS overlay not going over the other components

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-ui-fabric

In Office UI Fabric JS, the overlay component does not go over the dropdown component. Is this to be expected or am I doing something wrong?

```js
var OverlayComponent = document.querySelector(".ms-Overlay");
var Overlay = new fabric['Overlay'](OverlayComponent);
var OverlayExampleButton = document.querySelector(".ms-Button");

OverlayExampleButton.onclick = function() {
  Overlay.show();
};

var DropdownHTMLElements = document.querySelectorAll('.ms-Dropdown');
for (var i = 0; i < DropdownHTMLElements.length; ++i) {
  var Dropdown = new fabric['Dropdown'](DropdownHTMLElements[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.2.0/css/fabric.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.2.0/css/fabric.components.min.css" />
<script src="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.2.0/js/fabric.min.js"></script>

<div class="ms-Overlay ms-Overlay--dark"></div>

<div id="content-main">
  <div class="padding">

    <div class="ms-Grid-row">
      <div class="ms-Dropdown" tabindex="0">
        <label class="ms-Label">Type: </label>
        <i class="ms-Dropdown-caretDown ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronDown"></i>
        <select class="ms-Dropdown-select">
          <option>Choose a type&amp;hellip;</option>
          <option>A</option>
          <option>B</option>
          <option>C</option>
          <option>D</option>
          <option>E</option>
          <option>F</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary" id="highlight-button">
            <span class="ms-Button-icon"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--plus"></i></span>
            <span class="ms-Button-label" id="button-text">Hello</span>
            <span class="ms-Button-description" id="button-desc"></span>
        </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would be considered a bug, but the fix is simple enough. Always make sure your overlays are defined *after* the content you want it to overlay (i.e. the bottom of the page).

```html
<div id="content-main">
 <!-- snipped for brevity -->
</div>
<div class="ms-Overlay ms-Overlay--dark"></div>
```

Alternatively, you specify an inline `z-index`. The default is `z-index: 0`. Setting it to `z-index: 1` will also ensure it's positioned over the other elements.

```html
<div class="ms-Overlay ms-Overlay--dark" style="z-index: 1;"></div>
```

Also, your example is using version `1.2` but the latest release is `1.5`. While it doesn't resolve this issue, it does resolve a slew of others you likely haven't run into yet.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.5.0/css/fabric.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.5.0/css/fabric.components.min.css" />
<script src="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.5.0/js/fabric.min.js"></script>
```